# Inserting Value in ordered Array?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I was trying to implement some sort of insert method for an Ordered Array in Java from John R Hubbard's Book [Data Structures with Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070146071) (Example 3.2) in-order to insert the elements and Sort the array more quickly than shifting elements or using bubble sorting .

Someone explain me what is happening in the below codes? How should I initialize variable 'k' (as an index array for 'a' array) and what should be the values for a (Since there are no values in the 0 and 2 index of array 'a' in image below).

[image]

```
void insert(int x){

    int i=0;
    while (k[i] != 0 && a[k[i]] < x) {  
        i = k[i];
    }

    a[free] = x;
    k[free] = k[i];
    k[i] = free++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Question #1:

> Can someone explain me what is happening in the below code snippet?

### Answer #1:

Lets first examine how one would iterate through such a structure and print out the elements in order. I'm using the example from the book in your question:

[image: Figure 1: Iterating an array with 2 level indexing]

Here's how it looks in Java:

```
int i = 0;
while (k[i] != 0) {
    System.out.println(a[k[i]]);
    i = k[i];
}
```

If you want to insert a value to such a structure, you have to know how to iterate it. You have to know the `i` of the first element (`a[k[i]]`) that is *equal to* or *greater than* the element you wish to insert (`x`):

---

Procedure `insert(x)` inserts `x` to `a[free]`.

Now the indices have to be updated to accommodate an extra link in the ordered chain. That is, to go from this:

```
| ... | a[k[i]] >= x | ... |
```

to this:

```
| ... | x | a[k[i]] >= x | ... |
```

The element directly after `x` is `a[k[i]]`. We have to temporarily detach it from the chain to insert `x`. Therefore: `k[free] = k[i]`.

Next, do: `k[i] = free`. `a[k[i]]` will now be `x` (remember, we inserted `x` to `a[free]`).

*Now* the magic happens. `a[k[i]] == x` and the element directly after it is `a[k[free]]` (which used to be `a[k[i]]` before).

Then `free` is incremented by one and we are done.

---

### Question #2:

> How should I initialise variable `k` (as an index array for `a` array) and what should be the values for `a`?

### Answer #2:

The example from the book looks just fine:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class IndirectReference {
    static final int Q = 0; // This value is irrelevant; added for clarity
    static int a[] = {Q, 44, Q, 22, 55, 33, 66, Q};
    static int k[] = {3, 4, Q, 5, 6, 1, 0, Q, Q, Q};
    static int free = 7;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        insert(50);
        
        System.out.print("a = ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        
        System.out.print("k = ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(k));
        
        System.out.println("free = " + free);               
    }
    
    static void insert(int x) {
        int i = 0;
        while (k[i] != 0 && a[k[i]] < x) {
            i = k[i];
        }
        a[free] = x;
        k[free] = k[i];
        k[i] = free++;
    }
}
```

**Note:** this procedure relies on the fact that `free` saves the index of the next free location in both tables.

In the example above, it's wrongly set to `8` after insertion of `50` because the procedure assumes there's always enough space at indices `free`, `free+1`, `free+2`, ... in both `a` and `k`.

Once you run out of free space you can either resize both arrays or compact them (put non-trailing `?`s at the end of both tables), though I can't quite see a clear way how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise `k` and `a` to be empty integer arrays:

```
int[] a = new int[10];
int[] k = new int[10];
int free=0;
```

The empty spaces in `a` are probably to illustrate what it could look like if there had been some deletions. If all you are doing is inserting, all elements of `a` before `a[free]` would have an inserted value, although it can still be 0 if you inserted a 0, but that's not what appears to have happened in the example.

As to what the code is doing, that's a bit of a longer explanation. The data values in `a` are our inserted data. The data values in `k` are references to index elements in `a` and `k` which we can follow to traverse our data in ascending order. The value of `k[0]` will always contain the index of `a` which has the lowest data value. So using the example from the book, `k[0]` is 3. `a[3]` is 22, and 22 is the lowest data value in our ordered list.

The data in `k` is also used to traverse the elements of `k`, and we always start at 0. So the next element would be `k[3]`, which contains a 5. `a[5]` is 33, the second-lowest number in our data.

So if we wanted to insert 27 into the list, and we follow this algorithm, the relevant entries in `k` are `k[0]==3`, `k[3]==5`, and `k[5]==1`. After we insert, `a[7]` will be 27 because `free` was 7 when we inserted (will be 8 after the insert). `k[0]` will still be 3, since 22 is still our lowest value data. `k[3]` will be 7, since our second-lowest data value is now 27 and is stored at `a[7]`. `k[7]` will be 5, since `a[5]` is 33, now our third-lowest data value, and `k[5]` is still 1 (hasn't changed).

So where we would have traversed our list following `k` indices 0,3,5,1,4,6 (according to the book), we would now follow this path: 0,3,7,5,1,4,6, giving us data values: 22, 27, 33, 44, 55, 66